# Minify jQuery tmpl html templates

Tags: javascript, html, templates, gruntjs, minify

I want to minify my .html file. I've tried to minify with [grunt-contrib-htmlmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-htmlmin), [grunt-processhtml](https://github.com/dciccale/grunt-processhtml). They actually couldn't minified. Then I realized that all my html elements wrapped in [jQuery.tmpl](http://skilldrick.co.uk/tmpl/). It seems these minify tools don't touch script tags. So I've bunch of templates looks like this:

```
<script id='wrapper' type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'>
  <div class='person-wrapper'>
    {{html $item.html()}}
  </div>
  <!-- many html tags -->
</script>
```

My question is how can I minify (jQuery.tmpl) templates? I'm using Gruntjs to minify .css, .js files. But any tool or plugin is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out [htmlcompressor](https://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/). According to their documentation it should compress code inside your template tags:

> Any content within `<pre>`, `<textarea>`, `<script>` and `<style>` tags will
>   be preserved and remain untouched (**with the exception of `<script
>   type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">` tags which are compressed as HTML**).

It's Java library but it also has [grunt plugin](https://github.com/jney/grunt-htmlcompressor).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using sublime text try adding this package which shall minify it for you:

[HTML COMPRESSOR](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/HTML%20Compressor).

Answer (score 0):

Not really the perfect solution, but this is what I do:

Minify just the HTML without wrapped in the script tags, then where ever you normally import them, use server-side includes. (In my case, PHP)

```
<head>
   <script id='wrapper' type='text/x-jquery-tmpl'>
     <?php require "templates/person.tmpl.min.html" ?>
   </script>
</head>
```

Comment: In my tmpl.html I've 72 templates which means 72 `script` tags. IMO minifying all templates separately isn't option.

Comment: Rough! Yeah, not the best plan. Does a JS minifier not work on the script tags?

Comment: aside: you really don't want to have 72 script tags in your app, compressed or not its a waste of time and resources.

Answer (score 0):

Your server should send this data gzip-compressed. Then any additional compression/minification is not necessary.

- https://superuser.com/questions/295360/how-to-know-if-a-site-is-gzipped

Edit: The benefit of minification+compression should be much less for HTML than for JavaScript. Because in HTML there are no function or variable names that can be rewritten like in JS.